# Background svg image flickering onhover action

Tags: css, svg, input, background-image

I'm using an input type range, where I have a svg for slider thumb.
This slider thumb svg changes with another svg on hover/active.
There's a flicker seen on first load of the web page.

I have tried loading both the images in before pseudo class of the input but doing this didn't help.

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   background: url('images/slider-range-thumb.svg') no-repeat;
   border-style: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   height: 77px;
   opacity: unset;
   width: 50px;
   appearance: none;
   margin-top: -38px;

   &:active, &:hover {
      background: url('images/slider-range-thumb-active.svg') no-repeat;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get a flicker. Maybe the problem is your SVG.

```css
input[type='range'] {
  width: 250px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#blackcat") no-repeat;
  border-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 95px;
  /*opacity: unset;*/
  width: 95px;
  appearance: none;
  margin-top: -47px;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:active,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat") no-repeat;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background-color: #777;
  height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

In this example I'm using this SVG:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100px" height="100px"  viewBox="0 0 225 225">

<style type="text/css">
 <![CDATA[  
    svg > svg:not(:target) {
    display: none;
    }
     ]]> 
</style>
<desc>
<g id="cat">
<path id="body" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M121.506,108.953c3.145-2.115,5.896-3.967,8.624-5.802
    c20.948,12.522,42.66,12.281,65.725,4.354c0.778,3.128,1.687,6.18,2.285,9.291c3.208,16.677,0.616,36.326-2.758,52.719
    c0,0-152.162,0.035-154.82,0.035c8.408,10.604,18.647,16.674,31.173,16.227c15.059-0.536,30.099-2.491,45.07-4.433
    c26.453-3.431,50.783,0.317,70.991,19.392c1.675,1.581,7.179,9.382,3.632,13.47c-3.524,4.062-12.062-1.289-13.795-3.036
    c-10.215-10.294-22.693-16.145-37.008-15.98c-14.568,0.166-29.103,2.376-43.679,3.216c-11.405,0.656-22.888,1.255-34.268,0.634
    c-9.862-0.538-18.646-5.258-25.691-12.131c-15.127-14.758-26.56-31.716-26.923-53.792c-0.396-24.125,17.008-44.198,40.835-48.153
    c23.477-3.897,43.372,4.666,62.051,17.569C115.82,104.515,118.537,106.717,121.506,108.953z"/>
<path id="head" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M129.747,18.651c3.646,6.147,7.048,11.646,10.189,17.291
    c1.404,2.523,2.761,3.481,5.888,2.718c14.09-3.439,28.227-3.932,42.396-0.046c1.308,0.358,3.815-0.733,4.608-1.923
    c4.043-6.072,7.705-12.398,11.814-19.149c8.693,15.648,15.012,31.447,13.169,49.204c-1.48,14.266-9.114,24.946-22.028,31.172
    c-17.641,8.503-35.969,9.511-54.067,1.823c-15.169-6.443-22.96-18.723-23.677-35.151C117.396,49.828,122.038,32.188,129.747,18.651z
     M189.467,81.017c7.232,0.084,15.334-6.867,14.292-13.652c-0.832-5.418-11.566-6.019-11.732-6.025
    c-7.238-0.308-13.768,6.133-14.144,13.949C177.731,78.444,182.773,80.938,189.467,81.017z M145.369,81.453
    c3.597,0.294,11.258-2.441,11.324-6.992c0.079-5.443-3.357-10.158-8.897-12.255c-5.807-2.197-16.523,1.484-17.065,5.19
    C129.692,74.494,138.107,81.089,145.369,81.453z"/>
</g>
</desc>
<svg version="1.1" id="blackcat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 225 225">
<use xlink:href ="#cat" fill="black" />
</svg>
<svg version="1.1" id="redcat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 225 225">
<use xlink:href ="#cat" fill="red" />
</svg>

</svg>
```

Inside of the main SVG there are 2 other svg elements with `display: none;` Please take a look at the URL I'm using for the thumb background: `cat.svg#redcat`, `cat.svg#blackcat`. By doing this I'm referencing only one of those two SVG elements so that I can use the `:target` selector to make the referenced SVG visible.

If this is not helping please add more code. A working example would be perfect.